# TSQL syntax not the same for SSMS and sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

Here is a simple tsql file :

```
# file foo.sql :
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Testing";

CREATE TABLE "Testing"
(
    "Id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "FilePath" NVARCHAR (442) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Testing" PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ("Id" ASC)
);

GO
```

When I load it through SQL Server Management Studio, all goes fine :

- connect to server, select a database
- open file 'foo.sql'
- run "Execute"
- output :

  ```
  Commands completed successfully.

  Completion time: 2019-11-07T10:48:37.3336032+01:00
  ```

When I use it as input through `sqlcmd`, I get an error :

```
> sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d DemoDb -i foo.sql
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server MY-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Testing'.
```

**Question**

How do I tell `sqlcmd` to behave like SSMS in this case ?

Should I use another command line tool which acts like SSMS ?

---

version information :

```
> sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 15.0.1300.359 NT
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

usage: ...
```

SSMS : v18.3.1

```
Component name                              Versions
SQL Server Management Studio                15.0.18183.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools    15.0.1487.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)     10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML                             3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                 9.11.18362.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                            10.0.18362
```

Comment: Try removing all your double quotes, you don't need them to delimit object names. You can wrap them in `[` and `]` if they have special characters, but I see none on this example. The problem is most likely a session variable that SSMS sets under the hood with quoted identifiers.

Comment: my question leans more to the side : how come a format is accepted by one shell and rejected by another ? what is specific about `"` in sqlcmd ?

Comment: Try adding `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` at the beginning of your script, this will allow using double quotes for objects. SSMS might set this ON by default, while sqlcmd might not. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Ezlo actually he does not need to add anything to the script.  He can just run the `sqlcmd` with the `-I` (enable quoted identifiers) switch.

Comment: As @tukan said, you should run sqlcmd with the -I flag to enable double quoted identifiers in script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLServer has a [QUOTE_IDENTIFIER {ON|OFF}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql) option, which modifies the effects of `"` in TSQL queries.

You can turn it on with `sqlcmd` by using the `-I` option :

```
sqlcmd -I -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d DemoDb -i foo.sql
```

or by explicitly adding the following instruction in your sql script :

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

---

SSMS usually sets up a bunch of session configurations when you connect to a server. You can find them on your **Options** window, under SQL Server (this is an example from old SSMS 2008):

[image]

[image]

You should check which ones you have enabled and which ones you don't, then you can add them at the start of your `.sql` file.

For this particular example, the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is making the execution by `sqlcmd` not identify correctly your object names that use double quotes, because it's set to `OFF`. You can add the `-I` parameter on `sqlcmd` to set this setting `ON` without modifying the script also.